# histogram or group users by number of campaigns they received

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I'm trying to bucket users by how many distinct email campaigns they receive. I want to be able to visualize similar to how "Count of Sessions" works.  I can get count distinct of campaign as a metric but need to turn it into a dimension. I've tried writing:

```
 Case
   when COUNT_DISTINCT(Campaign = 1) then "1"
   When COUNT_DISTINCT(Campaign =2) then "2"
   When COUNT_DISTINCT(Campaign =3) then "3"
   else "more"

   End
```

The end result I would like is a table that looks something like this:

- Received 1 campaign, X amount of users
- Received 2 campaigns, Y amount of users
- Received 3 campaigns, W amount of users
- ... (and so on)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible since `CASE` aggregation only works over report dimensions but not over actual user records.